# Error when doing multidimensional integration using anonymous functions

Tags: matlab, anonymous-function, numerical-integration

I am trying to perform multidimensional integration, using the following algorithm:

```
y= @(a,b,c) a+b+c; %function - 3 dim
y1=@(a,b) integral(@(c) y(a,b,c),-20,20); % L,H - limits for  c`
y2=@(a) integral(@(b) y1(a,b),-20,20); % L,H - limits for b
y3=integral(@(a) y2(a),-20,20); % L,H - limits for a
```

but this gives the following error:

```
Error using integralCalc/finalInputChecks (line 515)
Output of the function must be the same size as the input. 
If FUN is an array-valued integrand, set the 'ArrayValued' option to true.

Error in integralCalc/iterateScalarValued (line 315)
                finalInputChecks(x,fx);

Error in integralCalc/vadapt (line 132)
            [q,errbnd] = iterateScalarValued(u,tinterval,pathlen);

Error in integralCalc (line 75)
        [q,errbnd] = vadapt(@AtoBInvTransform,interval);

Error in integral (line 88)
Q = integralCalc(fun,a,b,opstruct);

Error in @(a)integral(@(b)y1(a,b),-20,20)


Error in integralCalc/iterateScalarValued (line 314)
                fx = FUN(t);

Error in integralCalc/vadapt (line 132)
            [q,errbnd] = iterateScalarValued(u,tinterval,pathlen);

Error in integralCalc (line 75)
        [q,errbnd] = vadapt(@AtoBInvTransform,interval);

Error in integral (line 88)
Q = integralCalc(fun,a,b,opstruct);
```

Can somebody please help me understand and fix my mistake, or suggest a better method?

*P.S.* 
I know about the `integral3` function, but I need this method, because I am going to try 4,5,6.... dimensions later.

Comment: For future reference: If you want debugging help, add more information in the question than "it does not work". Add desired behavior or error ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if this will work in any possible case, but it works quite well for this simple case. Just use symbolic maths.

```
syms a b c
y=a+b+c;
y1=int(y,c,-20,20)
y2=int(y1,b,-20,20)
y3=int(y2,a,-20,20)
```

However, careful creating the variables. Don't create `yn` dynamically!

Comment: Thank you it seems to be fine)

Answer (score 1):

To understand *why* you're getting this error, let's rewrite your code using "regular" functions:

```
function q42536274
  y3(-20,20);
end

function out = y(a,b,c)
  out = a + b + c;
  % The result of the above is some [1x150 double] vector. No problem here.
end

function out = y1(a,b,L,H)
  out = integral(@(c)y(a,b,c),L,H);
  % The result of the above is the scalar [-1.421085471520200e-14]. Problem!
end

function out = y2(a,L,H)
  out = integral(@(b)y1(a,b,L,H),L,H);
end

function out = y3(L,H)
  out = integral(@(a)y2(a,L,H),L,H);
end
```

This is what the workspace looks like at the time of the error:

[image: Workspace when the error appears]

Now we can see what MATLAB was complaining about: the amount of elements in `fx` and `x` is different! How is MATLAB supposed to numerically integrate in this scenario? `0`-order approximation? This is ambiguous.

We need to tell MATLAB how to get out of this mess. One of the ways we can do it is like this:

```
function out = y1(a,b,L,H)
  out = ones(size(a))*integral(@(c)y(a,b,c),L,H);
  % Now the result of the above is also a [1x150 double] vector. Yey!
end

function out = y2(a,L,H)
  out = ones(size(a))*integral(@(b)y1(a,b,L,H),L,H);
  % Same as above...
end
```

Thus we get the output `-2.2737e-11` which is "pretty close" to the correct answer of `0`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation)